# how to pass javascript variable value to views.py function in django?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am trying to send a string generated from javascript tag in my html page to views.py function. I'll use that value to render it to another html page where another javascript will use it.

This is the variable which parses json data:

```
var url = data.result.docs[i].source.enriched.url.url;
```

I want to send "url" to my function in views.py but i am not able to figure out a way.

Also i want to keep a link, so that when user click it the "url" is passed to views.py and my function there send it to other html file.

```
sjd += "<br/>" + data.result.docs[i].source.enriched.url.title +
            '<a href="/rawHtmlText/url">' + ' Read more' + '</a>' + '<br>'
```

This is kind of link i would like to have in my page.
I know urls.py should have a proper pattern, but i am not able to figure it out.

May be jQuery can be used but I am a noob in this field so kind of stuck here.

Please guide me.

Comment: you can have a route variable in django like `GET "/rawHtmlText/:url"`, and you can grab `url` there. I'm not familiar with Django, but I'm sure it should have a facility to grab variables from routes.

Comment: i am confused doing that cz of trying out different solutions of different posts but none of them working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just build an AJAX query. Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = data.result.docs[i].source.enriched.url.url;
        $("#send-my-url-to-django-button").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/process_url_from_client",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    url: url,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                success : function(json) {
                    alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");
                },
                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Assuming you have a button on  your page like this:

```
<button type="button" id="send-my-url-to-django-button">Send URL to Django View</button>
```

Clicking that button should send the `url` to your Django view. Then on the Django side, you can access the `url` like so:

```
def process_url_from_client(request):
    url = request.POST.get('url')
```

Comment: Along with passing value to view i want to navigate to other html page. Because the other javascript calls other API with this url and parses JSON there.

Comment: If you want to redirect, just call `window.location.replace('http://take-me-somewhere');` right after `alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");`.

Comment: Not working. Is it possible to keep <a href /> tag instead of button?

Comment: Sure. The link could either POST directly to your view, or you can handle that asynchronously with AJAX. If you decided to use AJAX, remember to call `preventDefault();`: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#preventdefault

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use anchor tag only, but in that case you will send data like this
    http://host/path_to_view.py/urlValueToSend. 
This will be a simple get request and url will be sent to the server
You may need ro encode the url as it contains special characters

```
var val = EncodeURI(url);
```