# How can we access java script variable in Django views.py

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I want to access a javascript variable in my views.py of a Django project

Comment: You cant. But you can use ajax call to send value to django.

Comment: Go and look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147248/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-value-to-views-py-function-in-django

Comment: you can not access javascritpt variable in python. because JavaScript used at frontend-side. and python(DJANGO) used at backend-side.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is created in your template, you can't. You can only pass data from your views.py into your template not the other way around.